# Layout Cache Issue

Tags: caching, layout, magento

I have a custom module I wrote that is pretty basic...it just adds a small block to the footer for tracking using Media Forge.  The  tag it adds is different depending on whether you're on a product view page or not.  This worked GREAT....until I turned on caching.  Now, if you flush the cache and load a product view page, you get the correct block for the product view page.  If you then go to another page (home, for instance), it still uses the product view page's block.  If I flush the cache and reload the home page, it's now using the right one, but if I go to a product page now, it's using the wrong one there.  So it's definitely a cache issue, I just don't understand how I'm supposed to correct this problem.

I'll paste the contents of my files below.  I look forward to any responses!

Layout XML file:

```
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <!-- DEFAULT TAG -->
    <default>
        <reference name="footer">
            <block type="core/template" name="mediaforge_footer" as="mediaforge_footer" template="tracking/mediaforge_default.phtml"/>
        </reference>
    </default>

    <!-- PRODUCT VIEW PAGES -->
    <catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="mediaforge_footer">
            <action method="setTemplate"><template>tracking/mediaforge_product.phtml</template></action>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
</layout>
```

config.xml for my custom module:

```
<config>
    <modules>
        <VPS_Tracking>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </VPS_Tracking>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <vps_tracking>
                    <file>vps_tracking.xml</file>
                </vps_tracking>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Added this to the end of footer.phtml:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('mediaforge_footer'); ?>
```

The module definition is pretty basic and the two template files *`mediaforge_default.phtml`* and *`mediaforge_product.phtml`* are pretty simple so I won't bother including them.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In a nutshell, you need to define a cache key for your block, which means you'll need to use something other than Mage_Core_Block_Template. When you create your own block, add this to the constructor:

```
protected function _construct() {
    $this->addData(array(
        'cache_lifetime' => 3600,
        'cache_key'      => $this->someMethodToDifferentiatePages(),
    ));
}
```

That last method needs to return a different string to every use case of the block (e.g. one for catalog pages, one for "other" if that's all you need). This will tell Magento which cached version to use

Hope that helps!

Thanks,
Joe

Comment: Thanks for your response, Joe.  Unfortunately, that didn't do the trick.  The problem, I think, comes down to the fact that the footer is cached by default, so anything _inside_ the footer is cached too, regardless of how I set cache settings on my block.  What I ended up doing was writing a custom Footer class that overwrites the **_construct** function and doesn't set the cache_lifetime or cache_tags data values.  Does that sound like the right way to handle it?  Seems to have worked...

Comment: That doesn't sound like the way to do it, but ultimately if it works that's the important thing. Alternatively, you could set the cache lifetime to zero or somesuch and try that. As long as it works, that's the right solution.

Comment: That's what scares me...  I am no Magento expert.  I've learned a lot over the last few months, but if disabling the cache for the footer is ultimately not a good idea, then what could that adversely affect?  I'd prefer to do it the right way, but either it didn't work or I didn't do something right.  Most cached pages in Magento use **cache_lifetime** and **cache_tags**.  Only a few use **cache_key**.  I can't find any info on what those mean and what I should use for them.  I guess I'll leave it for now, but any additional info would be appreciated.

Comment: [This wiki](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/block_cache_and_html_ouput) explains the meanings of **lifetime**, **tags** and **key**. Perhaps the best approach is to write a footer descendent (which you've done correctly) and set it's key to something that uniquely identifies a footer-per-page, such as the URL.

Comment: That wiki doesn't _explain_ anything.  There are a few examples, but it doesn't tell you what are valid values for **cache_tags** or why they suddenly include **cache_key** in the second example.  But whatever, it's working, so I'm happy :)